# Getting the ID of the most recent DIV with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a webpage that dynamically prepends new divs about once per minute.

Here is what the HTML code basically looks like:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<div id="freshcontent">
 <div id="501">Stuff 2:18pm</div>
 <div id="500">Stuff 2:12pm</div>
 <div id="499">Stuff 2:09pm</div>
 <div id="498">Stuff 2:05pm</div>
</div>
```

I want to retrieve the id of the most recent div that is inside the "freshcontent" div, which would be "501" in the example above.

Then I want to take the id number and insert it into some Jquery code, which I have here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
   setInterval(function() {
   $("#container").load("/webpage/?id="+THE_ID_NUMBER_GOES_HERE);
  }, 10000);
 });
</script>
```

So I have 2 questions:

1. How do I get the id of the most recent div (which is constantly changing)?
2. How do I insert it into my Jquery code?

I'm new to Javascript/Jquery, so I'm not sure how to do this. I've tried using .first() and .closest(), but I can't get it to work.

Comment: `$("#freshcontent div").first()`? or is it not always the first div in freshcontent?

Comment: Just to make sure you aren't missing anything - you get the ID of your element by running .attr('id') on your element, in this case your code should look like `$("#freshcontent > div:first").attr('id');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### how

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  setInterval(function() {
   var id = $('#freshcontent > div').first()[0].id;
   $("#container").load("/webpage/?id="+id);
  }, 10000);
 });
</script>
```

### why

`$('#freshcontent > div')` selects all direct `div` children in #freshcontent.

`first()` selects the first in the selected collection.

`[0]` gets the underlying html element.

`id` is the javascript property of an element that represents it's "id".

### but...

This doesn't include error handling,. If your "freshcontent" is empty, an error will be thrown in your js console and an ajax call will be made to "/webpage/?id=undefined".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
  setInterval(function() {
   var first = $('#freshcontent > div').first();
   var id = "default value";
   if(!!first.length) {
     id = first[0].id;
   }
   $("#container").load("/webpage/?id=" + id);
  }, 10000);
 });
</script>
```

provides some error handling, making an ajax call with a "default value" to fetch the first few elements.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
   setInterval(function() {
   var divId = $("#freshcontent > div:first").attr('id');
   $("#container").load("/webpage/?id="+divId);
  }, 10000);
 });
```

Comment: `var divId = $("#freshcontent > div:first");` is just a jQuery-reference to the `div`, but not its `id`-attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an example [on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/bYvaz/)

It illustrates two ways to get the most recent id, one uses the implicit ordering (this is an assumption based on your example HTML), the other actually checks the numbers and returns the largest.

The examples on JS Fiddle are also noted below:

Implicit order:

```
var itemId = $('#freshcontent div:first').attr('id');
```

Independent of order:

```
var itemId = 0;
$("#freshcontent div").each( function () {
    itemId = Math.max(itemId, parseInt(this.id, 10));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var recentDiv = $("#freshcontent div:first");
```